# How to access the Rest API published over WSO2 API Manager within organization from internet

Tags: rest, wso2-api-manager

I am new to the WSO2 API Manager concept. We did a small POC and successfully published and subscribed a restful webservice as an API over WS02 API Manager. We were able to access it successfully within the organization using token.

```
Ex: URL - http://MylocalMachineName:8080/rest/api/xyz/12345 
Authorization : Basic + wso2 token
```

Now we want users outside of the organization to be able to access the service. Currently we can't invoke the URL from internet/outside the organization and test it because we were still at POC stage.

My Question is how can the internet users who are outside the organization access this rest API published over WS02 API manager? How will WS02 API manager resolve the outside calls?

To my knowledge every domain name should be registered with a DNS (Domain Name Server), which identifies a domain name with a unique Internet Protocol (IP) address.

So do we need to configure any DNS settings to access my rest API over internet? If Yes, How to do it?
I looked at the documentation and other stuff on the internet. But I didn't find any clear info on it

Comment: if your server has public ip address. Then you can access the api manger thorough that ip. If you want you can get a domain name for your ip and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally what we do is deploy api manager in a clustered setup and expose only gateway worker nodes to external users.

First check this article on  [WSO2 API Manager deployment patterns](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/API+Manager+Deployment+Patterns). This describes common patterns used to deploy API manager in a production environment

You can also check this article on deploying api manager cluster setup in Amazon web services [api manager cluster setup in Amazon web services](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager+in+Amazon+Web+Services). It contains step-by-step instructions to create and deploy a WSO2 API manager cluster in AWS. It contains all the steps on exposing API manager to outside

Comment: Sorry for late reply..but I didn't understood your answer